# Why MySQL Workbench shows connection error related to known_hosts?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

While connecting to database on remote server I got connection error related to known_hosts file.

It did not ask me to update the known_host file but simply reject to connect.

Comment: Yes it's not a question, but I thought that it might be useful for others.

Comment: @Strabek, not a bad idea to post some useful experiences. But you must do this as question and answer. Hence change your info above to become a question and answer your own question.

Comment: @Mike Lischke, done it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found the solution:

**MS Windows 7 Professional**:

Go to `C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\ssh` and delete known_hosts file (C:\ is the drive where your MS Windows is installed).

Above will remove all hosts that you connected to and MySQL Workbench will ask you again to accept new hosts.

Comment: On my Windows 10 box the known_hosts file was under C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\.ssh

Comment: thanks, i couldn't connect to my database for hours :)

Comment: the known_hosts file will be found under  `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh`

Answer (score 32):

For Windows 10, MySQL Workbench appears to use a `known_hosts` file in a standard location:

```
C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\known_hosts
```

If you are happy that the server fingerprint has changed, you can remove the related line, and try the operation again in Workbench.

Comment: `C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%` looks buggy as a path name, as USERPROFILE is already the user profile path. Is it USERNAME instead? or is it a bug from MySQL?

Comment: I think when I wrote this @Jean I was just referring to the file location, rather than to a specific path string that MySQL/Workbench has to process. In other words, users wanting to amend their known_hosts file should traverse there manually, in their Windows Explorer, in order to find the file that Workbench is using.

Answer (score 3):

This also works fine for Ubuntu version of Mysql Workbench (found [here](https://forum.level1techs.com/t/mysql-workbench-ssh-error/127332))

Create an empty file here : ~/.ssh/known_hosts_empty

Now in Workbench, go to Edit => Preferences… => SSH (left-hand column). On the right-hand side, there is a field “Path to SSH known hosts file”. Click on the “Browse” or “…” button to locate the empty file you just created. Selecting the empty file and pressing OK will effectively clear your known SSH hosts.